# How to Create a Slim Docker Image for Cloud Build with Bazel, Kubectl and Gcloud Installed?

Tags: docker, gcloud, bazel, kubectl, google-cloud-build

I want to run a [k8s_objects](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s) Bazel rule from a Google Cloud Build step, which deploys new configurations to my cluster. Hence I need a Docker image with

- **bazel** (obviously for running bazel targets)
- **kubectl** (for applying new configuration to my cluster)
- **gcloud** (for authenticating to my Google Kubernetes Engine cluster)

installed. Currently I have [this huge docker image](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/blob/9f0344b4ba03b8f66205618122efe5a2fede2f84/docker/slim-bazel-kubectl.Dockerfile) which is 1GB in size and probably cluttered with stuff I don't need. Therefore my build times skyrocket to 10 minutes and more.

This is how my `cloudbuild.yaml` looks like:

```
steps:
  - name: eu.gcr.io/cents-ideas/slim-bazel-kubectl
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        gcloud container clusters get-credentials cents-ideas --zone europe-west3-a --project cents-ideas
```

#### What would a small docker image with only the packages I need look like?

Comment: An example of a smaller Dockerfile that has **bazel**, **kubectl** and **gcloud** you can find [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s/blob/master/images/gcloud-bazel/Dockerfile).

Comment: awesome, I'll try that! :)

Comment: I think this image is out of date. Getting error: `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder613695822/gcloud.pub.gpg: no such file or directory`

Comment: Please double check because the `COPY` instruction in the `Dockerfile` copies the files in `src` to `dest` folder. You must be either missing the `gcloud.pub.gpg` file or building the Dockerfile from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I use the image below. However it doesn't have `kubectl` installed

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg unzip python python3 git build-essential

# nodejs
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs

# yarn
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
  echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && \
  apt-get update && apt-get -y install yarn

# bazelisk
RUN yarn global add @bazel/bazelisk --prefix /usr/local && bazelisk version

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "bazelisk" ]
```